# Using T-SQL to update a table row by row based on previous rows value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have a table in which i'm trying to create an ID field based on the date difference between the current start date and the previous rows end date

the table looks something like this:

```
Table ID     |     Person ID    |     Start Date    |     End Date   
   1         |        1         |     01/01/2019    |    03/01/2019         
   2         |        1         |     03/01/2019    |    05/01/2019         
   3         |        1         |     07/01/2019    |    10/01/2019         
   4         |        1         |     10/01/2019    |    16/01/2019         
   4         |        1         |     16/01/2019    |    16/01/2019         
   5         |        1         |     18/01/2019    |    20/01/2019
```

What I want it to do is to compare the current rows start date to the previous rows end date, if the difference is greater than 1 then we want to increment the New ID field by 1. and if it is Less than 1 we want to keep this new field as the same as previous row (see example below)

```
Table ID     |     Person ID   |      Start Date    |     End Date     |  NEW ID Field
   1         |        1        |      01/01/2019    |    03/01/2019    |     1
   2         |        1        |      03/01/2019    |    05/01/2019    |     1
   3         |        1        |      06/01/2019    |    10/01/2019    |     2
   4         |        1        |      10/01/2019    |    16/01/2019    |     2
   4         |        1        |      16/01/2019    |    16/01/2019    |     2
   5         |        1        |      18/01/2019    |    20/01/2019    |     3
```

The code I currently have to do this updates the entire table at once rather than row by row, and I want to avoid the use of cursors as much as possible due to this being a fairly large table and will slow down our process by a fair chunk.

My code at the moment is:

```
DECLARE @rown INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @Val INT
SET @rown = 1
SET @max = (select count(*) from dbo.table)
SET @Val = 1


WHILE @rown <> @max


Update dbo.table
  SET New_id_field = 
  (select Case WHEN LT_Flag = 0 then NULL
        WHEN 
        DateDiffFromPrev *-1 >1 
        THEN @Val + 1
        ELSE @Val
        END)

 FROM dbo.table t1
 INNER JOIN
 (
      SELECT 
      table_ID
      ,person_ID
      ,start_date
      ,end_date
      ,LT_Flag
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY start_date) AS rownumber 
      ,DATEDIFF(day,  start_date, coalesce(lag(end_date) over (partition by Person_ID, LT_Flag order by start_date), start_date)) as DateDiffFromPrev  
FROM ) t2  
     ON t1.table_id = t2.table_id

SET @rown = @rown + 1

END
```

Apologies for any formatting in post as i'm new to stack overflow!
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: For the description *" if the difference is greater than 1 then we want to increment the New ID field by 1. and if it is Less than 1"* what about when the difference is 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WHILE` is a really bad solution to this. You would be far better off with the analytical function `LAG` and then a windowed aggregate. Note that I don't know what the logic is for when the difference is 1 day (as per my comment), so you will have to correct that:

```
WITH Prev AS(
    SELECT V.[Table ID],
           V.[Person ID],
           V.[Start Date],
           V.[End Date],
           LAG(V.[End Date],1,V.[End Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY V.[Person ID] ORDER BY V.[Start Date]) AS PrevEndDate --Not ordered on [Table ID] as it is not unique in the OP's data.
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,CONVERT(date,'01/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'03/01/2019',103)),         
                (2,1,CONVERT(date,'03/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'05/01/2019',103)),         
                (3,1,CONVERT(date,'07/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'10/01/2019',103)),         
                (4,1,CONVERT(date,'10/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'16/01/2019',103)),         
                (4,1,CONVERT(date,'16/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'16/01/2019',103)),         
                (5,1,CONVERT(date,'18/01/2019',103),CONVERT(date,'20/01/2019',103)))V([Table ID],[Person ID],[Start Date],[End Date]))
SELECT P.[Table ID],
       P.[Person ID],
       P.[Start Date],
       P.[End Date],
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,P.PrevEndDate,P.[Start Date]) < 1 THEN 0 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,P.PrevEndDate,P.[Start Date]) > 1 THEN 1
                --WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,P.PrevEndDate,P.[Start Date]) = 1 THEN ???
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY P.[Person ID] ORDER BY P.[Start Date]
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +1 AS [New ID]
FROM Prev P;
```

Comment: Wow this is fantastic, works like a dream many thanks for this!!!